# Jquery find object in an Angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs-directive, find

First of all, is it possible to use Jquery to find an object in an Angular directive?

ie:

```js
MyApp.directive('test',[function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        templateUrl: "/Scripts/Angular/Directives/Templates/test.html"
    };
}]);
```

```html
//Directive template 

<section id="Foo" class="black-overlay">
    ...
</section>
```

And when you do ie:

```js
(function(){
  console.log($("#Foo"));
})();
```

Seems jquery can not find Foo, and it works if Foo is not inside an directive. Any ideas regarding to this? Thank you !

Comment: Where are you trying to run that code (with the console.log)?

Comment: Where do you call your directive? Having an ID inside a directive is not a good idea, directives are meant to be re-usable.

Comment: The idea is to reuse a piece of html markup code, quite static. So the first idea came to me is to make it as a directive. And in my case it's a loading screen, it will be unique, so using ID in this case is not a problem.

Comment: The console.log was an example, I ran it in the html page where the directive is used.